# Find relation between 2 numbers (username and password)

Tags: pattern, formation-of-numbers

I have a two sets of Usernames and passwords as follows:

User --> Password

1456 --> 3473

1360 --> 3377

Now I have to find the password for 1301.

Could anyone please help find the relation (it is known to have a relation between the user and password) and hence the password for 1301?

Thanks!

Comment: This is hard with two examples

Comment: It appears that the resulting answer was actually really easy, but that shows that there was little to no work or investigation done by the OP and they just went straight to PSE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty easy:

> $xyzt->xyzt+2017$

so the answer is

> $3318$

Comment: i think your answer would be more readable if you didnt separate xy and zt, and just had it as one number, especially given the current times. +1 either way.

Comment: @indubitablee fixed it :)